# How to bounce a number within a range?

Tags: math

I'd like to request help in form of pseudo-code for bouncing or "ping-ponging" a number in a range, by which I mean adding a number to another value in a range, where that number instead of exceeding the range or being clamped to it, is continuously bounced back into it.

**Example**

Consider the following variables:

Range: `(-2, 2)`
Starting value in the range: `1`
Added value: `14`

The number would start at `1` and go through 14 alterations, as following:

```
2
1
0
-1
-2
-1
0
1
2
1
0
-1
-2
-1
```

The code I am trying to write would only return the final number of this sequence, which is `-1`.

**Specifications**

— The code must not use a `while` loop.
— The code must be able to work with non-integer values.
— The code must be efficient and fail-proof.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. This isn't a free code writing service. What have you tried so far? We can help you with concrete issues to concrete problems.

Comment: I attempted to run a loop that checks if the number is outside the range, ran the number of times equal to the value divided by the difference of numbers of the range. If it was exceeding it, it would substract the lowest boundary of the range or if it was less than the range, it would add the highest boundary of the range. However, that worked in only half the cases I tested and I am not able to find a better solution.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what language you are working in.

Comment: Anything similar to JavaScript should do.

Comment: @poaawo You should show us.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a for loop that goes for the number of steps specified.
Inside the loop add to a running total the value of each step using a variable to hold the step value, and when you hit the limit multiply the step value by -1 to get it going in the other direction.

For the number of steps required
Add value to total
If total exceeds upper limit
Value *= -1
If value is less than lower limit
Value *= -1

Return the total when the loop ends

Edit: I'm on my phone and psedocode bit formatting got borked

Comment: This would be a workable solution if only integers would be involved, however it will not work if the range or added number is less than 1.

Comment: Sure it will, just make the running total and added number a double, boom you can add decimals.

Answer (score 0):

First, compute `cycle = 2 * (max - min)` and find the largest integer `n` such that `cycle * n` is less than or equal to `added value`. One way to do this is to calculate `full cycles = round_toward_zero(added value / cycle)`. We can immediately subtract from `added value` the value `cycle * full cycles` because moving by `cycle` returns you to where you started and headed in the same direction, so we only need to consider the portion of `added value` that is strictly greater than an even multiple of `cycle`. Let us define `modified value = added value - cycle * full cycles`.

Next, calculate `position = starting position + modified value`. Given that `min <= starting position <= max`, there are three cases for position:

1. `position < min`. In this case, `modified value` must have been negative, so we can simply "bounce right" by calculating `position' = min + (min - position)`. There are two sub-cases now:

   - `min <= position' <= max`: simply return `position'` as the answer
   - `max < position'`: we must "bounce back" again by calculating `position'' = max - (position' - max)`. This time, `position''` is guaranteed to be between `min` and `max` since `modified value` is guaranteed to to be between `-2 * (max - min)` and `0`... so just return `position''`.
2. `min <= position <= max`. In this case, no additional bouncing is required, so just return `position`.
3. `position > max`. In this case, `modified value` must have been positive, so we can simply "bounce left" by calculating `position' = max - (position - max)`. There are two sub-cases now:

   - `position' < min`: we must "bounce back" again by calculating `position'' = min + (min - position')`. This time, `position''` is guaranteed to be between `min` and `max` since `modified value` is guaranteed to be between `0` and `2 * (max - min)`... so just return `position''`.
   - `min <= position' <= max`: simply return `position'` as the answer

Example:

```
Range: (-2, 2)
Starting value in the range: 1
Added value: 14

min = -2
max = 2
starting position = 1
added value = 14

cycle = 2 * (max - min) = 2 * 4 = 8

full cycles = round_toward_zero(added value / cycle)
            = round_toward_zero(14 / 8)
            = round_toward_zero(1.75)
            = 1

modified value = added value - cycle * full cycles
               = 14 - 8 * 1
               = 6

position = starting position + modified value
         = 1 + 6
         = 7

position = 7 > 2 = max

position' = max - (position - max)
          = 2 - (7 - 2)
          = 2 - 5
          = -3

position' = -3 < -2 = min

position'' = min + (min - position')
           = -2 + (-2 - -3)
           = -2 + 1
           = -1
```

Now, this might seem like a lot of calculations. For small numbers of steps, it might be faster just to do a loop. However, for large added values, this approach is significantly better.